# Filter By Partial Integer Pandas

Tags: pandas, filter, integer

[image]

I have a dataframe that I want to filter by fip code instead of just using the state column. If I wanted to select all rows whose "fips" column value starts with 53, for Washington State, how would I do that?  I'd rather not convert the type to a str and use str.startswith.  I am looking for the equivalent of str.startswith but for an integer.  My input data frame is the first image and my expected output dataframe is the second image. Data is from the ny times site to track the corona virus that is freely available on github.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Let us try

```
subdf=df.loc[df.state.eq('Washington') & df.fips.astype(str).str[:2].eq('53'),:].copy() 
#adding the copy here try to avoid the copy warning when you modify the selected data frame
```